# TSQL to Eliminate Repetitive Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have pretty basic table schema.

```
Table A
TEMPLATE_ID    TEMPLATE_NAME
```

Table A has the following rows

```
1 Procs
2 Letter
3 Retire
4 Anniversary
5 Greet
6 Event
7 Meeting
8... etc.
```

Table B

```
TEMPLATE_ID    VALUE
```

Table B has 100K+ rows with `TEMPLATE_ID` connecting the two tables.

Now the execs want a sample of 20 records of types 1-5 from table A. I could do something basic...which is about my speed when it comes to TSQL.

```
SELECT TOP(20) B.VALUE FROM TableB
JOIN TableA ON
B.TEMPLATE_ID = A.TEMPLATE_ID
AND TableA.TEMPLATE_NAME IN ('Procs', 'Letter'...)
```

But that isn't quite right as I end up with 20 rows...in other words I was expecting 100 rows. 20 for each.

Is this one of those areas where partition could be used. I can see how I would break TableB into partitions for each template (tableA) but I'm not sure how I would limit it to 20 rows.

OK so I could just cut and past into Excel 20 rows from each partition...I could also write 5 very basic queries...but this is kind of an academice...improve my knowledge pursuit.

So to clarify. 20 records from each of the first r template types.

TIA

Comment: thanks for the edit @guildbounty...I hadn't noticed how bad the formatting turned out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ROW_NUMBER and partition the data based on the template_name and return only 20 from each partition

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT B.VALUE, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TableA.TEMPLATE_NAME ORDER BY ( select NULL)) as seq
FROM 
TableB
JOIN TableA ON
B.TEMPLATE_ID = A.TEMPLATE_ID
) T
where T.seq <=20
order by B.VALUE
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER...that's what I was missing. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try?

```
SELECT B.VALUE
FROM
(
    SELECT TEMPLATE_ID,VALUE, DENSE_RANK ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY TEMPLATE_ID ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS RANK_NO
    FROM TABLE_B
) B INNER JOIN TABLE_A A ON (A.TEMPLATE_ID = B.TEMPLATE_ID)
WHERE A.TEMPLATE_NAME IN ('Procs', 'Letter'...)
AND B.RANK_NO <= 20
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a *ranking function*. You first partition your data, order each partition and apply the ranking function:

```
select seq = row_number() over (
               partition by table_catalog , table_schema , table_name
               order by column_name
               ) ,
       *
 from information_schema.COLUMNS
```

The above code partitions the rows in `information_schame.COLUMNS` on the fully-qualified table/view name to which they belong. Each partition is then ordered alphabetically and given a `row_number()`.

That then gets wrapped in another select which makes use of it. This code pulls the first 3 columns for each table in the system based on column and provides some information about it:

```
select t.table_name   ,
       t.table_schema ,
       t.table_name   ,
       t.table_type   ,
       c.seq ,
       c.ordinal_position ,
       c.COLUMN_NAME ,
       data_type = c.data_type + coalesce('('+convert(varchar,c.character_maximum_length)+')','')
                 + case c.is_nullable when 'yes' then ' is     null' else ' is not null' end
from information_schema.tables t
join ( select seq = row_number() over (
                      partition by table_catalog , table_schema , table_name
                      order by column_name
                      ) ,
              *
       from information_schema.COLUMNS
     ) c on c.table_catalog = t.table_catalog
        and c.table_schema  = t.table_schema
        and c.table_name    = t.table_name
where c.seq <= 3
order by t.table_catalog ,
         t.table_schema  ,
         t.table_name ,
         c.seq
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT B.VALUE, TableA.TEMPLATE_NAME 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.TEMPLATE_ID ORDER BY NEWID() ) as row 
    FROM TableB
    JOIN TableA 
      ON A.TEMPLATE_ID = B.TEMPLATE_ID 
     AND A.TEMPLATE_ID <= 5 
) T
where T.row <= 20
order by B.VALUE
```

Comment: Down vote care to respond.  Posted the same time as the accepted answer.  The accepted answer does not have "the of the first r template types."